# Spring Boot - Hibernate is not saving Date properly

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, date, spring-boot

I am trying to **save a Date into my MySQL database using Hibernate**, everything works fine apart from one thing...

**It only saves the day, month and year**, completely ignoring the minutes and seconds which are important for my project.

*Here is the bit in my entity class where I declare the 2 date columns:*

```
@Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
@NotNull(message = "Please provide a start date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startDate;

@Column(name = "end_date", nullable = false)
@NotNull(message = "Please provide an end date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date endDate;
```

*This is code snippet from the part that creates an example row into the table:*

```
repository.save(new Product(
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2018-02-21 
15:30:14.332"
)));
```

It creates and saves the new entity succesfully, but when I go take a look, the **start_date and end_date columns contain only the yyyy-MM-dd part of the date**.

I would like some help on how to get the full date, including the time into the DB.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the full package name of the Date that you're using? I suggest you take a look at Java 8's java.time package and start using Instant. Save the date as Long (in mills) in the DB and only convert to human readable date when you have to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next:

```
@Column(name = "start_date", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
```